# wordpress custom "add new post" page

Tags: wordpress, admin, posts

i want to present to authors who register to my site a custom "add new post" page. I mean when they try to make a new post they will click the posts->add new and they will be presented with specific fields to fill. Like filling a custom form with textboxes and dropdown lists.

If anyone can give me some ideas..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these plugins will work for you... Or at least might give you a good start for what you're looking for.  The idea behind these is that you can simply edit content on the "front end" of your site (without getting into the WordPress back end).

- [Front End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/)
- [Quick Post Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/)
- [Simple Front End Edit Buttons](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-front-end-edit-buttons/)
- [WP Insert Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-insert-post/)

These plugins may or may not integrate with WordPress's built-in registration (author) authentication.  If not, I'm sure you could wrap the code in an author logged in check.

This plugin looks good for giving authors the ability to include an "About Me" section in the footer of their article:

- [Author Box 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-box-2/)

If you aren't familiar with WordPress development and are interested in learning, I'd recommend getting the book [Digging Into WordPress](http://digwp.com) (and accompanying blog).  Otherwise I'm sure you can hire a developer to implement what you need.

Comment: thanx for the feedback i ll have a look. i also read an article about custom write panel [link]http://wefunction.com/2009/10/revisited-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/ which i think will help me

Comment: the plugins are irrelevant. i want when authors loggin to be presented with a custom write panel and not the default.

Comment: i found the custom field template plugin but i dont know if it works with wordpress 3.1. this plugin is closest to my needs.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  Sorry, thought you wanted to know how to let your authors just "add a page" from the front end "view" of your site (without logging into the back end).